# Python for loop counter list - counter not working

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Could someone please help me troubleshoot my code.
I have two lists.

```
    A = [['2925750', ' Everything he mentioned, I could have evaluated on my own'], ['2925750', ' I do wish he could have shown us more at this point that could have set the fox apart.']]

B = ['mentioned','evaluated','fox','wish']
```

The goal is to append to list A the number of times any item in B is present in a sentence for A.

The result should be something like:

```
[(['2925750', ' Everything he mentioned, I could have evaluated on my own'], 0), (['2925750', ' I do wish he could have shown us more at this point that could have set the Equinox apart.'], 0)]
```

The problem is my count is zero.

Below is my code. Thank you in advance:

```
Y = []


##Find Matches
for sent in A:
  for sent in B:
      Y.append((sent, sum(sent.count(col) for col in B)))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you used 'sent' twice.
- You don't need a loop for B.
- 'A' is a list of lists.

My fix:

```
Y = []
A = [['2925750', ' Everything he mentioned, I could have evaluated on my own'], ['2925750', ' I do wish he could have shown us more at this point that could have set the fox apart.']]
B = ['mentioned','evaluated','fox','wish']

for sent in A:
    o = 0
    for i in sent:
        o +=sum(i.count(col) for col in B)
    Y.append((sent, o))
```

Y:

> [(['2925750', ' Everything he mentioned, I could have evaluated on my
>   own'], 2), (['2925750', ' I do wish he could have shown us more at
>   this point that could have set the fox apart.'], 2)]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

The variable `sent` in `for sent in B` overshadows the variable in `for sent in A`.  Or, to be more exact, it assigns to the same name (same variable).

You should rename one of them.

Also, note you already iterate over `B` inside `sum`. In the inner loop, you probably meant to iterate over each of the lists in `A`.

```
for lst in A:
  for sent in lst:
      Y.append((sent, sum(sent.count(col) for col in B)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `sent` as the iterator for both loops as it is still in scope.